# React native setInterval useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval, use-state

I'm creating interval counter and below code is working fine. But I have few questions about this code which I do not understand.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

const Interval = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`seconds: ${seconds}`)
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {seconds} seconds have elapsed since mounting.
        </Text>
      </View>
  );
};

export default IntervalExample;
```

1. Why this is not working if I put `setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);` instead `setSeconds(seconds + 1);` more simply ?
2. Why `` console.log(`seconds: ${seconds}`) `` is always log as `0` ?

Comment: I check it, and your code works. The only problem in your code is that you haven't properly close the Text tag.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar sorry and thanks for mention it, I edited my post. Yes It is working fine. But I wanted to know two things about the code which I mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1):

use this ;

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds + 1);
      console.log(seconds)
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [seconds]);
```

Comment: Ok. So the reason for that is not mentioning the changing variable i.e. `seconds`

Comment: `[seconds]` is unnecessary when using `setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1)`

Comment: There's no need to run the effect every time the value of seconds changes. This will also cause previous interval to be cleared and a new interval to be created at every interval, which is totally useless.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar if this is not inside a useEffect block, interval won't get unmount and process will run forever, even move to another screen.

Comment: @JohnStuart I didn't say that you shouldn't put it inside useEffect. What I said is that you should pass an empty dependency array. And use setSeconds(seconds=>seconds+1).

Comment: @TayyabMazhar But in that case I can not use `seconds` as a param to some other function isn't it ?

Comment: @JohnStuart You can. Just store the new value in a local variable before returning it from setSeconds, then pass that variable to any function you want.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar Ahh ok, storing new value in a local variable should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to run `useEffect` You need to pass variables as the second parameter (in your case, it is `seconds`). When this variable has changed then `useEffect` will be run again.

From docs:

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing extra work is less of a problem.

that is way, You need to pass second varable to useEfect:

```
useEffect(() => {...}, [seconds])
```

and in that case You can use `setSeconds(seconds + 1);` instead of passing function.

Complete code:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const interval = setInterval(() => {
   console.log(`seconds: ${seconds}`)
   setSeconds(seconds + 1)
  }, 1000)
 return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [seconds])
```

Comment: Thanks. Nicely explained.